# C# OleDB - Oracle Stored Procedure not returning data

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures, oledb

I have the following C# code that is calling a stored procedure, but no data is being returned (empty/null dataset.) If I run the stored proc in TOAD, I definitely get results (one row.) I can change the command text to "SELECT * FROM DUAL" and I get data returned, so I know the database is making a successful connection. The stored proc takes one input parameter, and outputs five fields. Here's my code:

```
        string connStr = "Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Data Source=database;User Id=username;Password=password;PLSQLRSet=1;";
        OleDbConnection oracleConn = new OleDbConnection(connStr);

        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("{call foo.bar(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)}", oracleConn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("p_login", OleDbType.VarChar, 50);
        cmd.Parameters["p_login"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        cmd.Parameters["p_login"].Value= "FOOBAR";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("p_user_id", OleDbType.VarChar, 50);
        cmd.Parameters["p_user_id"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("p_user_role", OleDbType.VarChar, 50);
        cmd.Parameters["p_user_role"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("p_user_first_name", OleDbType.VarChar, 50);
        cmd.Parameters["p_user_first_name"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("p_user_last_name", OleDbType.VarChar, 50);
        cmd.Parameters["p_user_last_name"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("p_user_terr_nbr", OleDbType.VarChar, 50);
        cmd.Parameters["p_user_terr_nbr"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "dsTest");
        return ds;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend inserting logging into stored procedure and seeing what kinds of data are sent to Oracle instance or if the procedure is called at all. And then debugging from there.

As of general, there may be some disconnection between data types you're sending or input/output parameters.

Comment: All the Oracle data types of in/out parameters are "varchar2"